What is best way to set time in a Rails app form so that the time is the same once I enter it and doesn't change?
I have a Rails 7 form where I enter in data to populate a database. I have a start_time and end_time in the form:
<%= f.time_select :start_time, :value => Time.now.strftime('%I:%M %p') %>
<%= f.time_select :end_time, :value => Time.now.strftime('%I:%M %p') %>

But after I entered the time it showed an hour off when I looked at the show page. So I read up on it and found documentation that said that I should add this to config/application.rb:
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

ok, so after I added that then the time number seems correct but the next day I noticed that the 1pm I entered was now showing as 1am. This was true for a lot of entered times.
I am in California. When I enter a time like 7pm into the form I want that time to stay as 7pm no matter what time zone is looking at it. How should I correct this?

There is no single right way to handle timezones in your application as it depends very much on your requirements. A common approach is to use UTC for everything on the backend and only perform conversions on the frontend. In general do not do Time.now.strftime('%I:%M %p') - while that might be what you prefer to see it's better to let the client localize the timestamps.

If you don't care about timezones and just want an actual number eg 7
Maybe consider just entering them as actual integers instead of time-fields ?
